# Printing a var inside a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JS and I want to know how to print a var inside a string ,
i found that the way should be :

```
var user = {
    name: "Mike",
    sayHi:() => {
        console.log('Hi, I\'m ${name}');
    }
};

user.sayHi()
```

but I get : `Hi, I'm ${name}`

Comment: You may wanna see the documentation for [Template Literrals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use backticks `` instead of regular quotes ''.

Answer (score 6):

When you want to use variables in string, you should wrap them in back ticks ` instead of double or single quotes.

So follow below example:

```
 console.log(`Hi, I'm ${name}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use backtick (``) instead of quotes ('') to evaluate the expression.

```js
var user = {
name: "Mike",
sayHi:() => {
  console.log(`Hi, I\'m ${user.name}`);
}
};

user.sayHi()
```

For more on [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
console.log(`Hi, I'm ${name}`);
```

To do string templating you need to use ` backquote. Single quote ' means just standard string

EDIT: As pointed by @peteb in the comments escaping single quote is not required in template string

Answer (score 1):

It should be a back tick not single quote. Please find below,

```js
var user = {
    name: "Mike",
    sayHi:() => {
        console.log(`Hi, I\'m ${name}`);
    }
};

user.sayHi()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 console.log('Hi, I\'m ' + name);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly or explain how the syntax differs from that in the question.